# How to make a Facebook Pages Crawler that gather all public pages of a specific country?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to make a Facebook Pages Crawler that gather all public pages of a specific country.
Especially pages that have more than 1000 fans.
How to best manage Facebook API request limit?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look at the Apache Nutch project (http://nutch.apache.org/about.html). Should be no problem to specify an URL prefix which pages should be indexed or not.